# Hangman Game - Unable to match input letters to word if the inputted letter sequence is jumbled

Tags: python, python-3.x

Below is an outline of what I am trying to built:

1. getting input from user about word length
2. sourcing word from text file according to user input word length
3. getting number of attempts from user input
4. display the word as *
5. Get hint letter input from
   user
6. Run the game

   - start by displaying the word in *
   - display the number of attempts remaining
   - prompt to input next letter

     - if input matches to the word

       - print "you guessed correct letter"
       - replace * from the word in the letter at appropriate space and print
       - print number of attempts remaining
       - print guessed letter
       - prompt to input next letter
         *this goes on until all the correct letter of the owrd has been guessed
       - print "You Won"
     - if input does not match to the word

       - print " you guessed wrong letter"
       - print the word in *
       - print number of attempts remaining
       - print guessed letter
       - prompt to input next letter
         *this goes on until remaining attepmt is 0
       - print "you lose"
     - if number of attempts is 0

       - print "no attempt left"
       - Print the correct word

The code is working only if the inputted letters are constant.

Let's say if the game word is "Rain", the code will work only if user inputs: "R", "A", "I", "N".

Code will not work if the inputted letters are jumbled, like, "A", R", "I", "N".

I believe it can be achieved through iteration using enumerate, but I am not sure how.

Here is my code:

```
import random

WORDS = "wordlist.txt"

"""Getting Length input from user and selecting random word from textfile"""
def get_word_length_attempt():
    max_word_length = int(input("Provide max length of word [4-16]: "))
    current_word = 0
    word_processed = 0
    with open(WORDS, 'r') as f:
        for word in f:
            if '(' in word or ')' in word:
                continue
            word = word.strip().lower()
            if len(word) > max_word_length:
                continue
            if len(word) < 4:
                continue
            word_processed += 1
            if random.randint(1, word_processed) == 1:
                current_word = word
        return current_word


"""Getting input of number of attempts player wants to have"""
def get_num_attepmts():
    num_attempt = int(input("Provide number of attempts you want: "))
    return num_attempt

"""Displaying word in *"""
def display_word_as_secret():
    display_word = '*' * len(get_word_length_attempt())
    print(display_word)

"""Getting hint letter from user input"""
def get_user_letter():
    user_letter = input("Enter letter: ").lower()
    if len(user_letter) != 1:
        print("Please Enter single letter")
    else:
        return user_letter

"""Starting Game"""
def start_game():
    game_word = get_word_length_attempt()
    attempts_remaining = get_num_attepmts()
    print('Your Game Word: ' + game_word)
    print('Your Game Word: ' + '*'*len(game_word))
    print('Attempts Remaining: ' + str(attempts_remaining))
    guessed_word = []

    while attempts_remaining > 0:
        next_letter = get_user_letter()
        if next_letter in game_word:
            print('You guessed correct')
            guessed_word.append(next_letter)
            print('Your Game Word: ' + game_word)
            print('Your Game Word: ' + '*' * len(game_word))
            print('Attempts Remaining: ' + str(attempts_remaining))
            correct_word = "".join(guessed_word)
            print(guessed_word)
            if correct_word == game_word:
                print('you won')
                break
        else:
            print('The letter in not in the game word')
            attempts_remaining -= 1
            print('Your Game Word: ' + game_word)
            print('Your Game Word: ' + '*' * len(game_word))
            print('Attempts Remaining: ' + str(attempts_remaining))

    else:
        print('no attempts left')
        print('You Lost')
        print('The Word is: ' + game_word)


start_game()
```

Comment: This is a great post. You have clearly shown the pseudocode that you developed as you tried to solve the problem and the resulting code when you implemented it. This is a lot of code to ask someone else to debug for you, though. I think you can break your problem down to a simpler description. Rather than describing what happens when you type all of the letters of the word, look at just the first letter that the user types. So in your example, the word to guess is "RAIN". What happens when the user types "R" as the first letter? Does your program correctly display `R***`?

Comment: What if the user instead types "A" as the first letter? Does your program correctly display `*A***`? If not, what does it show instead?

Comment: Thanks @Code-Apprentice!!! I am still learning how to put up a question properly.

I haven't yet able to do what you suggested. This is because I didn't quite got the iteration part of Python. Honestly I tried but I couldn't do it. I am still modifying the code and hopefully will be able to do that tomorrow. As of now I got my query resolved :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're constructing `correct_word` from the guessed letters in the order they were entered by the user. A guessed string `'ARIN'` is not equal to `'RAIN'`.

Instead, you need to do a comparison that doesn't care about the order. The simplest fix would be to change

```
if correct_word == game_word:
```

to

```
if set(correct_word) == set(game_word):
```

because sets will be compared for their content regardless of the order. It will also cope better with repeated letters, for example `'letterbox'` will just be treated as the collection of letters `{'b', 'e', 'l', 'o', 'r', 't', 'x'}`.

You might as well store the guessed letters as a set in the first place because it doesn't make sense to guess the same letter more than once anyway.

Comment: I learned about SET and yes that fixed the issue. I am not sure why it didn't came to me all this time, probably a problem with newbies. Thank you so much for you response and clarification!!

Comment: I will modify it further now.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you describe is in line `guessed_word.append(next_letter)`
In effect you append letters in the order they are given by the player. Which is fine if you just compare the set of letters and number of occurrences, for example by using `counter` from `collections`. Or you can figure out where each supplied letter stands in the subject word and reconstruct that from user input

Comment: My next goal is to try to do that. Replace the displayed secret word, i.e, * with the correct input letter.

But I am not sure of the logic enough now.

Comment: The answer with `set` is much better than my way. No need to keep track of poaitions or occurrences, because they do not influence player's success